# what is the effect of Big-endian or Little-endian on the members of structure?

Tags: c, endianness

Given below code snippet :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
union xyz
{

    int j;
    char b[2];
}y;


int main(void)
{

    y.j=520;
    printf("%d %d",y.b[0],y.b[1]);
    y.b[0]=2;
    printf(" %d ",y.j);
    return 0;

}
```

For this code , I am not getting whether that whether the system is little endian or Big-endian , if y.j is 520 then we have the representation as :

> 0000001000000100  , so y.b[0] should be 2 and y.b[1] should be 4 ,but I am getting y.b[0] as 4 and y.b[1] as 2 ,and my machine is little-endian ,but I am not getting how is the architecture affecting the representation of y.b[0] and y.b[1] ?

In my opininon , whenever we create array there is nothing like Most significant byte of array and least significant byte of array , we have indexes like b[0] , b[1] , b[2] and so on , so then how is the architecture affecting the representation of array ?

Please explain .

Comment: Are you sure that an int is only two bytes on your system? To be safe you should use int16_t or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on the safe side, let's use `short int`, which is more likely to be 16 bits.

```
union xyz {
    short int j;
    char b[2];
} y;
```

So after you say

```
y.j = 520;
```

then `y.j` looks like this:

```
     +-------------+
y.j: |         520 |
     +-------------+
```

On a big-endian machine `y.b` looks like this:

```
     +------+------+
y.b: | 0x02 | 0x08 |
     +------+------+
        [0]    [1]
```

On a little-endian machine `y.b` looks like this:

```
     +------+------+
y.b: | 0x08 | 0x02 |
     +------+------+
        [0]    [1]
```

Comment: to be on the safe side, it wold be better to use `(u)int16_t`, but yeah `short int` has a very high likelyhood to be 16bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is little endian. So the least significant byte is stored first. For your example that is 0x08. The upper byte will be 0x02.

`y.b[0]` access the first byte in memory. Not the first byte from left to right as the number is written on a page. So `y.b[0]` access 0x08, and `y.b[1]` accesses the second byte as stored in memory i.e. 0x02.

If your machine was big endian (and ints were 16 bit) then the first byte of the int stored in the memory would be 0x02, and the second byte would be 0x08. So `y.b[0]` would access 0x02, and `y.b[1]` accesses the second byte as stored in memory i.e. 0x08.